# Objective-C - Static field or an ivar for a primitive type

Tags: objective-c, static, ivars

I've recently got stuck in the middle of choosing between an ivar and static field. For instance: I need to toggle traffic lights between red and green. So I put a flag called isRed.I've so far used a static bool for this purpose and it has served quite well. Now I think I can also use instance variables for this but I don't know the difference between them.What is the real difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know that there is (and ever will be) exactly one traffic light in your application, you can use a variable with static storage duration (what you call a static field).

In almost all cases it is preferable to put state into the classes that control the state – i.e. to use an ivar. This approach is called "object oriented design".

Comment: Ok, so even the term I use for this case is wrong:I mean the "static field", as I can infer from your answer it should be called static storage instead.

Comment: Well, most people call it static variable or so. The problem is that this term is not very clear. There are variables in functions/methods with the `static` modifier. These variables are not global, yet live as long as the process is running. Then there are compilation scope variables (outside of functions, sometimes global) that have the same lifetime. This lifetime is called "static storage duration". When `static` is added to these variables it means that the variable is private to the compilation unit.